# Optional second argument must be defined if first argument is of a certain type

Tags: typescript

I have a function that is meant to be called as either

```
myFunc("")
myFunc({}, {}) // two different objects
```

it can also be called like

```
myFunc("", {})
```

in which case the second argument is simply ignored.

I want to prevent it from being called without a second argument if the first argument is an `obj` instead of a string

```
myFunc({}) // should type error
```

I implement this like this

```
type SomeType = { name: string }
type SomeOtherType = { config: number }

function myFunc(firstArg: string | SomeType, secondArg?: SomeOtherType): number {
  if (typeof firstArg === "string") {
    return doStringStuff(firstArg)
  }
  if (secondArg === undefined) {
    throw new Error('secondArg must be defined when firstArg is SomeType')
  }
  return doObjStuff(firstArg, secondArg)
}
```

(where `doStringStuff()` and `doObjStuff()` both return numbers) but is there a better way to do this? At the type level?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that function overloading works here, surprisingly even for variable argument counts ([Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQBQAcCMAXIgM5QBOMYA5gJTEBucMAJgNwBQoksCKGWPEURwARgCsAptAA0iXACZiYqdHqImrTt2jwkaTJCHEylGogA+IidKhzFym9EuIwIADbvEAXlcf36posiADeiAC+HBwGggDksbScMUYh4XKpidECKeGZyTjx6blJ2TipcvF5pdiFiJVsQA)):

```
function myFunc(p1: string): void;
function myFunc(p1: object, p2: object): void;
function myFunc(p1: string | object, p2: object | null = null): void { }

myFunc(''); // OK
myFunc({}, {}); // OK
myFunc({}); // Error: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
myFunc('', {}); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
myFunc({}, ''); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
myFunc('', ''); // Error: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use overloads to ensure that in TypeScript you can't call with a `string` and `SomeTye`:

```
function myFunc(firstArg: string): void
function myFunc(firstArg: SomeType, secondArg: SomeOtherType): void
function myFunc(firstArg: string | SomeType, secondArg?: SomeOtherType) {
  if (typeof firstArg === "string") {
    return doStringStuff(firstArg)
  }
  if (secondArg === undefined) {
    throw new Error('secondArg must be defined when firstArg is SomeType')
  }
  return doTypeStuff(firstArg, secondArg)
}


myFunc("", { name : ""}) // error
myFunc("") // ok
```

You could also use a union of tuples in rest parameters to help TypeScript understand the relationship between parameters:

```
function myFunc(...{ 0:firstArg, 1:secondArg, length }: 
  | [firstArg: string]
  | [firstArg: SomeType, secondArg: SomeOtherType]) {
  if (length === 1) {
    return doStringStuff(firstArg)
  }
  return doTypeStuff(firstArg, secondArg)
}


myFunc("", { name : ""}) // error
myFunc("") // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3lAdgQyQC4oBnYAJwEtcBzKAXwFgAoUSWRCAeWAAsIFVB0w4AxnFwAzKrRK4ArggBGgxq1ZSFuMcCqSoCEADFtYgBQA6azgAMRGRXIBBCrQA0UAIxFSECbgAJq4eUAA2EHT8jCSsUFAAPlAA2o4ubiTk1HQAunGJKWnAISTwSMIQnn4BwRmcSLwCQmg5AJTY+VRSUOYRUXxQ6EPe7Vj58RQQwAoUuFCBcDCUNLRLClJS5kUhrfnMLBNTM3MLFWsbW1ROxW5V-pK1tLss+xosRqY65gBE3544BCQUBIvwY7QA9OCoIIKHAKKwPmYft8IVC4ABrN5aHR6AwLJbZVbTC6kTLLOijN6vFjY3T6E5wM7EzbbOplFBoO41EIAflKXEaggqlJYrAYQA)

The union of tuples will act like overloads at call site so your callers aren't expose to the tuples

Comment: I'm more interested in making the `throw new Error` not happen. `myFunct({name: ''})` should never happen. In fact it would be nice if I could delete that `if` statement completely, but I think you've answered my question, I can do this with overloads.

Comment: in fact, `myFunc("", { config: 2})` is exactly the thing I *want* to allow, it's simply ignored

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy You want to allow `myFunc("", { config: 2})` ? The code seems t ignore the second parameter if the first one is string. I added a version with better implementation types

Comment: I've edited my question to be more clear. If you want to see the function in context, it's this one: https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/6e85f379beab660deeceb32d4a9d9f62d92c1b37/src/generators/python.ts#L716-L725